# Can redshift occur from relative velocity or just from expanding space?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, space-expansion, doppler-effect, redshift

With sound, the Doppler effect is caused by the wavelength of the sound being affected by the relative velocity between the observer and emitter, eg. If they are moving toward each other the observed wavelength is shortened.

However, given the speed of light is constant from the perspective of any observer, does this same effect still apply?

I can imagine if you were to observe an object travelling toward you at a significant % of c, you would see a similar wavelength of light to a stationary object firing a similar pulse. (I think that this is due to time dilation effectively negating the compression of the wavelength, e.g. the emitter observes emitting a pulse in a short timeframe but I observe that same pulse being emitted over a longer timeframe due to relativity).

If my instinct here is correct, do all redshifts occur as a result of expanding space and not actual velocity of objects?

Comment: Fully covered by https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect

Comment: @RobJeffries Thanks for posting that link, I think what that says is that the doppler effect does apply to light but I really don't follow as to why. In the article it states that `The wavefront moves with velocity c but at the same time the observer moves away with velocity v, so lambda + vt = ct.` Doesn't that imply that the relative velocity of the wavefront is less than c? I'm not really a physics guy, I just find this interesting but I'm struggling to understand the explanation and conclusion of this article.

Comment: You need to think about number of wavecrests received in a second, not about the wavespeed (which is always the speed of light).

Comment: @RobJeffries I guess that's my question, if I'm moving away from the source doesn't time dilation increase the occurrences of crests in the source at the same rate as the doppler effect decreases them? (to preserve c)

Comment: No. How would time dilation increase the frequency? Time dilation causes a redshift whether the source is moving towards, away, or even at right angles.

Comment: @robjeffries hmmm interesting maybe thats where im getting it wrong ill have a think about why i was thinking that

Answer (score 0):

There are three sources of electromagnetic Doppler shift.

1. Special relativity: Since [energy is **not** Lorentz invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_scalar#Energy,_rest_mass,_3-momentum,_and_3-speed_from_4-momentum) and [$E_{\gamma}=h\nu$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_relation), the frequency of light must similarly **not** be Lorentz invariant.
2. Gravitational attraction: Since the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) tells us that gravitational effects aren't locally observable for someone in free fall, General Relativity is a **locally** inertial theory. That is, there is local Lorentz invariance and we can assume a locally Minkowski spacetime. [From this, we can predict a Doppler shift due to gravitational fields as they are equivalent to if the source of the light was itself accelerating.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift)
3. Cosmic expansion: In an expanding universe, objects that are not bound together (via some attractive force) move apart from each other. This can be observed in the motion of distant galaxies. From said motion, a Doppler shift is produced. Since our universe has an accelerating expansion, [objects further away appear to move away faster, resulting in a greater redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law). Yes, this does mean that energy is ultimately not conserved in our universe on a cosmic scale - a consequence consistent with the [Noether symmetry of time invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#Example_1:_Conservation_of_energy).

Comment: "Since our universe has an accelerating expansion, objects further away appear to move away faster, resulting in a greater redshift." This is true even when the expansion isn't accelerating.

Comment: Should be noted that (1) and (2) are the same effect in different coordinates, and (3) is just an example of (1) and/or (2). (see https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1081)